# Copy the contents of the array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The simplified following code is not correct. I want to write into the array YY_ that is supplied to `operator()`, was wondering how can do it? Seemingly the issue is that it is assuming that copying pointers copies the contents of the array?!

```
double *computeY(double const *const *xx){
  const int i0 = 0;
  const int i1 = 1;
  static double YY[2];
  YY[0] = xx[i0][0] + xx[i1][0];
  YY[1] = xx[i0][1] + xx[i1][1];
  return YY;
} 

struct computeYFunctor{
   computeYFunctor(){}
   bool operator()(double const *const *xx_, double* YY_) const{
     YY_ = computeY(xx_);
     return true;
  }
 };
```

Comment: Copying pointers does not copy the contents of the array.

Comment: You are passing `xx_` into the function. What's the problem with passing `YY_` as the second parameter? No need to `return` anything. Everything else unchanged.

Comment: Copying pointers does just that, copying pointers. What is the objective? I don't find that in your question.

Comment: A copy of a pointer is another pointer which points to the same object.  Pointers are separate entities to the objects they may be pointing to.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just followed the way here is suggested to use pointers as the return value to then iterate through arrays:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_return_arrays_from_functions.htm

Still not sure what is the difference

Comment: @JohnBM What is your objective? To copy the _pointed-to_ objects or to copy the pointers to those objects?

Comment: @TedLyngmo copying the content of `YY` to `YY_`

Comment: @JohnBM If so, you are going about it the wrong way. If you describe the bigger problem you are trying to solve you may be able to get rid of the `static double` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, pointers can be difficult.  I'm taking a swag at this but I don't have time to check my code, and there are going to be folks here 100,000 times more qualified to do this better then I am... but here we are.

You need to pass the pointer to YY as an argument to computeY()

```
void computeY(double const *const *xx, double *YY ){
  const int i0 = 0;
  const int i1 = 1;                // array is  (pointer math)
  YY[0] = xx[i0][0] + xx[i1][0];   // YY[0] is *(YY+0)=val
  YY[1] = xx[i0][1] + xx[i1][1];   // YY[1] is *(YY+1)=val
  // So the two lines YY[0] reached out to the addresses YY+0 and YY+1
  // And modified the data.
} 

struct computeYFunctor{ 
   computeYFunctor(){}
   bool operator()(double const *const *xx_, double* YY_) const{
     computeY(xx_, YY_);
     return true;
  }
 };
```

Good Luck and I hope this helps.  I don't do much operator overloading in my work, so there is a good chance I'm missing something a 12 year old would catch here.

Comment: thanks it worked. I'm not sure what I am missing about how the pointers and array are related. because here it says we can iterate through arrays by pointers:
https://flylib.com/books/en/2.253.1/relationship_between_pointers_and_arrays.html

Comment: I took another look at your code and I think it could possibly work in 'C'.  But with C++ I'm thinking the compiler decides double* and double[2] are different things.
Perhaps a cast
return (double*)YY;
instead of
return YY;
might have satisfied the compiler.
In the RUST language where memory has ownership this passing of a pointer out from within is safe, but in 'C'/'C++' its often tricky to figure out who allocate the pointer.
So I always like to pass in pointers rather than have them passed out from a function.